# Rails thinks model with attr_accessor is valid but it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have a model with `attr_accessor` and I'm adding an error to this attr_accessor. Why does it valid? The code below is self-explainable, I think:

```
class Dealer < AR::Base
  attr_accessor :keyword_data

  def keyword_data=(file)
    begin
      parse_values(file)
    rescue CSVKeywordsParser::ReadError => e
      errors.add(:keyword_data, e.message)
    end
  end
end

>> dealer.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff586359610 @base=#<Dealer id: 6, name: "Something">, @messages={}>
>> dealer.errors.any?
=> false
>> dealer.add :keyword_data, "xxx"
=> ["xxx"]
>> dealer.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff586359610 @base=#<Dealer id: 6, name: "Something">, @messages={:keyword_data=>["xxx"]}>
>> dealer.errors.any?
=> true
>> dealer.valid?
=> true
```

How can I add error to `attr_accessor` which will be tracked via activemodel, so, `dealer.valid?` will return `false` (as it's need)?

Comment: `valid?` runs all validations. In order to return meaningful values with `valid?` you have to add validations to your model.

Answer (score 1):

See the course for `valid?`. It first clears any errors, then runs the validations. If you add an error manually it won't see it. Weird, but so says the source. Fix would be to add a validation for `keyword_data` so it gets picked up automatically.

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  run_validations!
ensure
  self.validation_context = current_context
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/107f4282bbfabc011d5ad3bcf3fb3c6fb812ad30/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L334

Comment: Can you explain me how to write this validation, please?

Comment: @asiniy not without knowing what that validation should be (which your code doesn't indicate)

Comment: Updated my `Dealer` class

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom The source you showed above is from ActiveModel. `valid?` method in ActiveRecord is a bit different https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/59190c037999d302dd95b1f53f7049c2cec3f7b9/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L56 .
 There is no `clear` process here. Can you explain that?

Comment: Interesting. Missed that, but still, this version calls `super` which I would hazard a guess (didn't check) calls the above which calls clear.

Comment: Ah, I see. It has `include ActiveModel::Validations` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/59190c037999d302dd95b1f53f7049c2cec3f7b9/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L31